# Python: How to make a script to continue after a valid string variable is returned

Tags: python

I got a question about a flow of definition in python:

```
def testCommandA () :
  waitForResult = testCommandB ()
  if result != '' :
     print 'yay'
```

Is there any way to make waitForResult to wait for testCommandB to return something (not just an empty string)? Sometimes testCommandB will produce nothing (empty string) and I do not want to pass empty string but as soon as I got a string in waitForResult then testCommandA will continue to run. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think we need a bit more context here. Is testCommandB() idempotent? Is it a function you've written?

Comment: It's a function I wrote. I just need the logic coz I tried to explain it in another thread but it just causing a lot of confusion

Answer (score 3):

```
# Start with an empty string so we run this next section at least once
result = ''
# Repeat this section until we get a non-empty string
while result == '':
    result = testCommandB()
print("result is: " + result)
```

Note that if `testCommandB()` doesn't block, this will cause 100% CPU utilization until it finishes. Another option is [sleep](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep) between checks. This version checks every tenth of a second:

```
import time

result = ''
while result == '':
    time.sleep(0.1)
    result = testCommandB()
print("result is: " + result)
```

Comment: @cloud68 By the way, I agree with Jon Clements that you should do this inside testCommandB() if it's possible and makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately 'while' does not work for me. It blocked the application so I can't do anything to produce the result. What I need is a 'wait' command but I dont know if such thing exists or not

Comment: @cloud68 You should be producing the result in testCommandB() right? The loop I posted just repeatedly calls that function until it returns a good result. You may want to include your testCommandB() so we can see what's going on. If you do need a "wait" function, that's why `time.sleep` does.

Answer (score 1):

Just return from `testCommandB` only where it's not an empty string. ie, have `testCommandB` block until it has a meaningful value.

Comment: This is my first thought but testCommandA kept running and gave me error that nothing is returned.... I need a "delay" function in testCommandA if there is any in python.

Comment: @cloud68 and how exactly does `testCommandA` keep running? Unless there's something going on that you're not describing - it should be blocked until a return of control from B

Comment: it flows right through and return this line :
# Result: <function testA at 0x0000000039167898> # 

Which obviously not what I want

Comment: @cloud68 It looks like you're doing `result = testA` instead of `result = testA()`. The `()` part is important because it tells it to actually call the function instead of just storing the address of the function.